# Send push notifications to audience defined by BigQuery result

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, push-notification, google-bigquery

Is any possibility trigger push notifications for specific group of users which is defined by BigQuery result. Is any way how to connect Firebase push notifications and BigQuery without programming some own backend service?

Use case is notify users based on retention other parameters queried from BigQuery.

I reached dead end in searching. So I am asking for help from someone skilled in google services or just way where to continue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for now, BigQuery doesn't provide a notification system. You could create a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).

Alternately, you could do this using some scripting, I found an interesting [Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701485/sending-email-through-firebase-cloud-functions), about sending an e-mail to users defined in a BQ table, by using Firebase Cloud Functions.

I hope it helps.